# Tell wget to mirror the parts of an URI's path to folders

Tags: command-line, download, wget, mirroring, download-manager

I have a list of URIs in a file `uris.txt`:

> http://example.com/file1.pdf
>   http://example.com/file2.pdf
>   http://example.com/Folder/file3.pdf
>   http://example.com/Folder/Subfolder/file4.pdf

The resulting directory structure on my HDD is supposed to be as follows:

```
|
|-file1.pdf
|-file2.pdf
|-Folder
  |-file3.pdf
  |-Subfolder
    |-file4.pdf
```

My current command is: `wget -i uris.txt -P downloads`

Unfortunately, wget flattens all directories, i.e. the filename is determined by concatenating the base directory (given by -P on the command line) and the last part of the URI's path.

Maintaining the directory structure a server serves is possible, albeit only with the [recursive mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Recursive-Download), which only operates on HTML and CSS as opposed to a given list of URIs.

Comment: You could use some regex-fu to convert the file list to more specific wget command lines then execute the file.

Comment: @NeilSmithline I actually generate the list by means of a Node.js script I wrote. I hoped wget has some built-in, ready-to-use functionality including dealing with special characters not allowed/preferred in directory names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get this with the extra options   `-x` or `--force-directories` and `-nH` or `--no-host-directories` to avoid the example.com top directory.

Answer (score 0):

Suggested reading that will provide the answer in a *future-proof* way:

`man wget`

Look for `--no-host-directories` and `--cut-dirs=number`

**--no-host-directories**
 will make wget skip creating a dir named "example.com" to put all data in.

**--cut-dirs=number**
Will do the same, for `number` subdirs, counting from the top.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but don't these options do the opposite, i.e. reducing the amount of directories? As a matter of fact, calling wget with the parameters  `--no-host-directories --cut-dirs=10` (10 being an arbitrarily chosen value) results in no difference compared to the execution without them.